# Reduce column width with multirow in latex

Tags: tables, spacing

Having problems with the second column is too wide and when I try to reduce it the vertical line doesn't fit the text

```
\hline
\textbf{Etiqueta} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Segmento}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Descripción}}\\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RA} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Torso} &  \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{\multirow{2}[4]{2.5in}{Articulación acromioclavicular.}} \\
\cline{1-2}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{LA} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Torso} &  \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RBAK}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Torso} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{Colocado cerca del ápice de la escápula derecho: se usa solo para identificar la izquierda y la derecha del esqueleto.} \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{C7} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Torso} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{Séptima vértebra cervical.} \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{T2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Torso} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{Segunda vértebra torácica.} \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{MAI} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Torso} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{Punto medio entre el ápice escapular izquierdo y derecho, cerca de las vértebras T10.} \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{IJ} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Torso} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{Hueco en la yugular. Región más superior del esternón, donde se encuentra con los huesos de la clavícula.} \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{PX} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Torso} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{Apófisis xifoides del esternón. Región más inferior del esternón.} \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{L1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Torso} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{Primeras vértebras lumbares.} \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{L3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Torso} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{Tercera vértebra lumbar.} \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{L5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Torso} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{Primeras vértebras lumbares.} \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RASIS} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{Pelvis}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{Espina ilíaca anterosuperior.}} \\
\cline{1-1}\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{LASIS} &       &  \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RPSIS} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{Pelvis}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{Espina ilíaca superior posterior.}} \\
\cline{1-1} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{LPSIS} &       &  \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RGT} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{Muslo}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{\multirow{2}[4]{2.5in}{La mayor prominencia lateral de la superficie externa del trocánter mayor.}} \\
\cline{1-1}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{LGT} &       &  \\


\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RTH}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}[4]{*}{Muslo}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{\multirow{4}[6]{2.5in}{Localizado cerca de la línea media del muslo. Se usa solo con el propósito de rastrear para distinguir el lado izquierdo del derecho. Para obtener el mejor resultado, desplace la altura del marcador entre el lado izquierdo y el derecho.}} \\
\cline{1-1}\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{LTH}}   &      &  \\
&       & \\
&       & \\
\hline
\newpage
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RLE} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}[4]{*}{Muslo}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{\multirow{3}[4]{2.5in}{La mayor parte de la prominencia lateral del epicóndilo femoral lateral. Junto con los marcadores LM, determina la ubicación del eje de la articulación de la rodilla.}} \\
\cline{1-1}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{LLE} &       &  \\
&       &\\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RHF} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{Pierna inferior}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{\multirow{2}[4]{2.5in}{Cabeza, extremo proximal del peroné.}} \\
\cline{1-1} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{LHF} &       &  \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RTT} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{Pierna inferior}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{\multirow{2}[4]{2.5in}{Borde más anterior de la tuberosidad tibial.}} \\
\cline{1-1}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{LTT} &       &  \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RSK}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}[4]{*}{Muslo}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{\multirow{4}[4]{2.5in}{Localizado cerca de la línea media de la espinilla. Se usa solo con el propósito de rastrear para distinguir el lado izquierdo y el derecho. Para obtener mejores resultados, desplace la altura del marcador entre el lado izquierdo y el derecho.}} \\
\cline{1-1}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{LSK}   &       &  \\
&       &  \\
&       &  \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RLM} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{Pierna inferior}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{\multirow{2}[4]{2.5in}{Ápice distal del maléolo lateral.}} \\
\cline{1-1}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{LLM} &       &  \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RCA} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}[4]{*}{Pie}} & \multirow{3}[4]{2.5in}{Cresta superior de la superficie posterior del calcáneo. El aspecto de la inserción del tendón de Aquiles en el calcáneo.} \\
\cline{1-1}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{LCA} &       &  \\
&       &  \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RVM} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}[4]{*}{Pie}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{\multirow{3}[4]{2.5in}{Cara dorsal de la cabeza del quinto metatarsiano.}} \\
\cline{1-1} {\multirow{2}[4]{*}{LVM}} &   & \\
&   & \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RFM} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{Pie}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{\multirow{2}[4]{2.5in}{Cara dorsal de la cabeza del primer metatarsiano.}} \\
\cline{1-1}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{LFM} &       &  \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RDP1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{6}[4]{*}{Pie}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{\multirow{6}[4]{2.5in}{Estos marcadores se agregan en la falange distal solo con el propósito de rastrear el segmento del dedo del pie y no se incluyen en el análisis biomecánico. Coloque el marcador cerca del final del dedo gordo del pie. Más específicamente, el marcador debe colocarse en el extremo distal de las primeras falanges.}} \\
\cline{1-1}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{LDP1} &       &  \\
&       &  \\
&       &  \\
&       &  \\
&       &  \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RME*} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{Muslo}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{\multirow{2}[4]{2.5in}{Prominencia medial del epicóndilo femoral medial.}} \\
\cline{1-1}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{LME*} &       &  \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RMM*} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{Pierna inferior}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{\multirow{2}[4]{2.5in}{Ápice distal del maléolo medial.}} \\
\cline{1-1}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{LMM*} &       &  \\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RSM*} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{Pie}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{17em}|}{\multirow{2}[4]{2.5in}{Cara dorsal de la cabeza del segundo metatarsiano.}} \\
\cline{1-1}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{LSM} &       &  \\

\hline
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide some more information about how your table is defined. E.g., do you use a `tabular` or `tabular*` environment? Which document class do you employ? How wide is the textblock? (Alternatively, how wide are the margins?)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution with use of the `tabularray` packages. In MWE below are considered most of the notes in @Mico answer (+1) and removed all empty rows too:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {My long table},
  label = {tab:longtblr},
                    ]{colspec= {l X[wd=5em] X[j]},
                      rowhead= 1,
                      row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
                      hlines, vlines,
                      vspan = even,
                      }
Etiqueta    &   Segmento    &   Descripción                     \\
% table body
RA      & Torso &   Articulación acromioclavicular.             \\
    \cline{1-2}    
LA      & Torso &  \\
RBAK    & Torso & Colocado cerca del ápice de la escápula derecho: se usa solo para identificar la izquierda y la derecha del esqueleto.       \\
C7      & Torso & Séptima vértebra cervical.                    \\
T2      & Torso & Segunda vértebra torácica.                    \\
MAI     & Torso & Punto medio entre el ápice escapular izquierdo y derecho, cerca de las vértebras T10.                                     \\
IJ      & Torso & Hueco en la yugular. Región más superior del esternón, donde se encuentra con los huesos de la clavícula.                    \\
PX      & Torso & Apófisis xifoides del esternón. Región más inferior del esternón.                                                       \\
L1      & Torso & Primeras vértebras lumbares.                  \\
L3      & Torso & Tercera vértebra lumbar.                      \\
L5      & Torso & Primeras vértebras lumbares.                  \\
RASIS   & \SetCell[r=2]{l} Pelvis
            & \SetCell[r=2]{j} 
            Espina ilíaca anterosuperior.                       \\
LASIS   &       &                                               \\
RPSIS   & \SetCell[r=2]{l} Muslo 
                & \SetCell[r=2]{j} 
                La mayor prominencia lateral de la superficie externa del trocánter mayor.                                \\
LPSIS   &       &                                               \\
RGT     & \SetCell[r=4]{l} Muslo
                &  \SetCell[r=4]{j} 
                Localizado cerca de la línea media del muslo. Se usa solo con el propósito de rastrear para distinguir el lado izquierdo del derecho. Para obtener el mejor resultado, desplace la altura del marcador entre el lado izquierdo y el derecho.  \\
LGT     &       &   \\
RTH     &       &   \\*
LTH     &       &   \\
RLE     & \SetCell[r=2]{l} Muslo 
                & \SetCell[r=2]{j} 
                La mayor parte de la prominencia lateral del epicóndilo femoral lateral. Junto con los marcadores LM, determina la ubicación del eje de la articulación de la rodilla.           \\*
LLE     &       &   \\*
RHF     & \SetCell[r=2]{l} Pierna inferior 
                & \SetCell[r=2]{j}
                Cabeza, extremo proximal del peroné.            \\
LHF     &       &  \\
RTT     & \SetCell[r=2]{l} Pierna inferior 
                & \SetCell[r=2]{j}
                Borde más anterior de la tuberosidad tibial.    \\
LTT     &       &  \\
RSK     & \SetCell[r=2]{l} Muslo 
                & \SetCell[r=2]{j}
                Localizado cerca de la línea media de la espinilla. Se usa solo con el propósito de rastrear para distinguir el lado izquierdo y el derecho. Para obtener mejores resultados, desplace la altura del marcador entre el lado izquierdo y el derecho.  \\
LSK     &       &  \\
RLM     & \SetCell[r=2]{l} Pierna inferior 
                & \SetCell[r=2]{j}
                Ápice distal del maléolo lateral.  \\
LLM     &       &  \\
RCA     & \SetCell[r=2]{l} Pie 
                & \SetCell[r=4]{j}
                Cresta superior de la superficie posterior del calcáneo. El aspecto de la inserción del tendón de Aquiles en el calcáneo.  \\
LCA     &       &  \\
RVM     & \SetCell[r=2]{j} Pie 
                & \SetCell[r=2]{j}
                Cara dorsal de la cabeza del quinto metatarsiano.   \\
LVM     &       & \\
RFM     &\SetCell[r=2]{l} Pie 
                & \SetCell[r=2]{j}
                Cara dorsal de la cabeza del primer metatarsiano.   \\
LFM     &       &  \\
RDP1    & \SetCell[r=2]{l} Pie 
            & \SetCell[r=2]{j}  
            Estos marcadores se agregan en la falange distal solo con el propósito de rastrear el segmento del dedo del pie y no se incluyen en el análisis biomecánico. Coloque el marcador cerca del final del dedo gordo del pie. Más específicamente, el marcador debe colocarse en el extremo distal de las primeras falanges.          \\
LDP1    &       &  \\
RME*    &\SetCell[r=2]{l} Muslo 
                & \SetCell[r=2]{j} 
                Prominencia medial del epicóndilo femoral medial.   \\
LME*    &       &  \\   
RMM*    & \SetCell[r=2]{l} Pierna inferior 
                & \SetCell[r=2]{j} 
                Ápice distal del maléolo medial.                    \\
LMM*    &       &  \\
RSM*    & \SetCell[r=2]{l} Pie
                & \SetCell[r=2]{j} 
                Cara dorsal de la cabeza del segundo metatarsiano.  \\
LSM     &       &  \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provide any information about your general document setup, so I had to make quite a few working assumptions. If they turn out to be incorrect, please let me know.

I must confess to not understanding why virtually every cell in the table is encased in a `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}` wrapper. The `\multirow` wrappers also seem to be quite unhelpful.

I would like to suggest that you (a) get rid of all of these wrappers, (b) get rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines as well, (c) get rid of the blatantly illegal `\newpage` directive, and (d) employ an `xltabular` environment; set its overall width to `\textwidth`, and use `l` as the column type for the first two columns and `X` for the third column. The resulting table will span more than a page; hence the need for an environment (such as `xltabular`) that can generate a page break "on the fly", i.e., wherever it may be needed.

The first few rows of the table are shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{xltabular} % 'xltabular' is a combo of 'longtable' and 'tabularx'
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % for \RaggedRight macro
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule, & \addlinespace macros

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} ll >{\RaggedRight}X @{}}

%% headers and footers:

\toprule
\textbf{Etiqueta} & \textbf{Segmento} & \textbf{Descripción}\\
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endfoot


%% body of table

RA & Torso &  Articulación acromioclavicular. \\
%\cline{1-1}    
LA & Torso &  \\

\addlinespace %\hline
RBAK  & Torso & Colocado cerca del ápice de la escápula derecho: se usa solo para identificar la izquierda y la derecha del esqueleto. \\

\addlinespace %\hline
C7 & Torso & Séptima vértebra cervical. \\

\addlinespace %\hline
T2 & Torso & Segunda vértebra torácica. \\

\addlinespace %\hline
MAI & Torso & Punto medio entre el ápice escapular izquierdo y derecho, cerca de las vértebras T10. \\

\addlinespace %\hline
IJ & Torso & Hueco en la yugular. Región más superior del esternón, donde se encuentra con los huesos de la clavícula. \\

\addlinespace %\hline
PX & Torso & Apófisis xifoides del esternón. Región más inferior del esternón. \\

\addlinespace %\hline
L1 & Torso & Primeras vértebras lumbares. \\

\addlinespace %\hline
L3 & Torso & Tercera vértebra lumbar. \\

\addlinespace %\hline
L5 & Torso & Primeras vértebras lumbares. \\

\addlinespace %\hline
RASIS & Pelvis & Espina ilíaca anterosuperior. \\
%\cline{1-1}
LASIS &       &  \\

\addlinespace %\hline
RPSIS & Pelvis & Espina ilíaca superior posterior. \\
%\cline{1-1} 
LPSIS &       &  \\

\addlinespace %\hline
RGT & Muslo & La mayor prominencia lateral de la superficie externa del trocánter mayor. \\
%\cline{1-1}    
LGT &       &  \\

\addlinespace %\hline
RTH   & Muslo & Localizado cerca de la línea media del muslo. Se usa solo con el propósito de rastrear para distinguir el lado izquierdo del derecho. Para obtener el mejor resultado, desplace la altura del marcador entre el lado izquierdo y el derecho. \\
%\cline{1-1}
LTH   &      &  \\

\addlinespace %\hline
RLE & Muslo & La mayor parte de la prominencia lateral del epicóndilo femoral lateral. Junto con los marcadores LM, determina la ubicación del eje de la articulación de la rodilla. \\
%\cline{1-1}    
LLE &       &  \\

\addlinespace %\hline
RHF & Pierna inferior & Cabeza, extremo proximal del peroné. \\
%\cline{1-1} 
LHF &       &  \\

\addlinespace %\hline
RTT & Pierna inferior & Borde más anterior de la tuberosidad tibial. \\
%\cline{1-1}    
LTT &       &  \\

\addlinespace %\hline
RSK   & Muslo & Localizado cerca de la línea media de la espinilla. Se usa solo con el propósito de rastrear para distinguir el lado izquierdo y el derecho. Para obtener mejores resultados, desplace la altura del marcador entre el lado izquierdo y el derecho. \\
%\cline{1-1}    
LSK   &       &  \\

\addlinespace %\hline
RLM & Pierna inferior & Ápice distal del maléolo lateral. \\
%\cline{1-1}    
LLM &       &  \\

\addlinespace %\hline
RCA & Pie & Cresta superior de la superficie posterior del calcáneo. El aspecto de la inserción del tendón de Aquiles en el calcáneo. \\
%\cline{1-1}    
LCA &       &  \\

\addlinespace %\hline
RVM & Pie & Cara dorsal de la cabeza del quinto metatarsiano. \\
%\cline{1-1} 
LVM &   & \\

\addlinespace %\hline
RFM & Pie & Cara dorsal de la cabeza del primer metatarsiano. \\
%\cline{1-1}    
LFM &       &  \\

\addlinespace %\hline
RDP1 & Pie & Estos marcadores se agregan en la falange distal solo con el propósito de rastrear el segmento del dedo del pie y no se incluyen en el análisis biomecánico. Coloque el marcador cerca del final del dedo gordo del pie. Más específicamente, el marcador debe colocarse en el extremo distal de las primeras falanges. \\
%\cline{1-1}    
LDP1 &       &  \\

\addlinespace %\hline
RME* & Muslo & Prominencia medial del epicóndilo femoral medial. \\
%\cline{1-1}    
LME* &       &  \\

\addlinespace %\hline
RMM* & Pierna inferior & Ápice distal del maléolo medial. \\
%\cline{1-1}    
LMM* &       &  \\

\addlinespace %\hline
RSM* & Pie & Cara dorsal de la cabeza del segundo metatarsiano. \\
%\cline{1-1}    
LSM &       &  \\

\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```